# Heroku Cannot find module in my backend app

Tags: heroku, build, typeorm

I'm learning front-end, but one day I had idea to create simple database.I have problem with open this app on the server. I'm using heroku.

[image]

my app tree:

[image]

my scripts:

`"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node build/server.js",
    "build": "tsc",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run client\" \"npm start\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"`

When I'm using `npm run dev` everything works. I added Procfile with:`web: node src/server.js`, but it doesn't fix. Can someone tell me how can I solve that problem?

PS build folder is hide via `.gitignore`

Answer (score 1):

From https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support:

> If a heroku-postbuild script is specified, the build script will not run.

Your code is not getting built by running tsc. `server.js` is not found 'cause it's not been generated in the first place.

Comment: I've solved this problem. At the moment I have : `0-05-25T11:58:13.203967+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/login" host=react-app-map-creator.herokuapp.com request_id=452bf76e-e2a5-4561-90f1-d92f8de2ce9d fwd="178.37.187.74" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=892 protocol=https` but my app doesn't work. Propably I should send to my client port of my server, but i don't know how. I've tried: `"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon src/server.ts --p $PORT"`

Comment: You should post a dedicated question about the new issue and mark this one as answered.